# Version control system advice

Tags: version-control

I'm maintaining a web based system which is quite big as in a lot of files and functionality and the time has come that others are going to work on it as well. It's an in-house enterprise solution so there are some wishes as to how to set this up:

1. I'm looking for a version control system that allows programmers to collaborate in an easy fashion
2. Some folders should not be accessible (e.g. certain modules) by users
3. I would like it to be self-hosted in a central place so there is one place that has the latest version of the system.
4. I already have an update system in place that looks for differences between files and database structure and applies these changes to the targeted website that needs to be updated.
5. I already have a webbased programming environment that directly changes files on the server and saves a copy of the saved file in the database for undo and diff purposes. This approach doesn't allow working on branches and then later push them which means no updates can be released as long as the whole system is not in a "production ready" state.

What would be a wise solution? As far as I know git doesn't have access control for specific files and folders. I also don't like the idea of freelancers downloading the whole repo just to change some files (they could steal the whole system)

I've looked into mercurial with a central repo but not sure if that would work.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Edit: the application is written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you have at least 3 solutions (there Git will be most weak and lame), based on common concept of "modular structure" of your app (in terms of separation parts of source-tree into independent repos):

- Git with submodules (no ACLs, rather hard self-hosted, no "collaborate in an easy fashion")
- SVN with externals (ACLs from repo- to single file level, easy self-hosting, but ordinary merge-hell and some other well-known weaknesses)
- Mercurial with subrepos  (good ACLs, rather usable self-hosting, easy learning curve even for newbies, but less fame and the number of qualified users)

Comment: I'm interested in your comment since you downvote Git so much, not that I don't like it, it seems really powerful, but it seems to not care about security inside a company, it's more aimed towards open source. I'm going to have a look into mercurial, `but less fame and the number of qualified users`, by less fame you mean `less populair` by picking a less common solution? I don't care lel, and qualified users as in people that are familiair with mercurial? They can learn ey, I need something that works for my business, I'm not here to please the people :p

Comment: @MisterrMoron - "Less fame" is just less fame: any code-monkey today "know" Git, but it's false for Mercurial side. "Qualified users" just in sense of less likely to find even in a noticeable sample person, who "know it, understand it and can use in brain-powered way just immediately"

Answer (score -1):

the best combination would be:

- git for ALL code repository

now that you chose git to use, there are two popular ways for read-only access:

- composer dependencies (or yarn, if that's a frontend web application)
- submodules

it is NOT POSSIBLE to revoke access to some files and still have the website running. but if you would like to prevent WRITE, then the separate repos or submodules is the way to go. I usually prefer to split the whole application into separate git repos and then link them through composer dependencies.

Note: You didn't state what is the web app written in, so I went with how it's usually done with the PHP web apps.

Comment: It's PHP, you were right about that. `I usually prefer to split the whole application into separate git repos and then link them through composer dependencies` How would that work? I only use composer to install certain packages...

2. Are submodules a `part of the repo` that certain users can access?

Comment: > How would that work?
If your app can be divided into namespaces, please keep the read-only namespaces in other repositories and have vendor/autoload.php do the work of loading them into your project.

> Are submodules a part of the repo that certain users can access?

No, submodules are more useful when there is no other dependency manager, so stick with composer dependencies.submodules are also different repositories that will be loaded into specific dirs (not vendor). this is described pretty well here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules